# How to update SSRS Subscription through metadata (Database)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005

Please help me to update all SSRS Subscriptions once using SQL Server database.

I appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Comment: What about the subscriptions do you want to update?  You need to provide a lot more detail here...

Comment: Wesley Marshall i would like update next run time in SSRS subscription through metadata.

Comment: I tried the below SQL Statement but no luck. 
update Schedule set [NextRunTime] = '2017-03-23 18:00:04.517' where [ScheduleID] = 'DB1CF401-342E-4681-AD99-424B394FFDA3'

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into Data Driven Subscriptions if you have enterprise edition. That way you can save and change values within a table vs having to touch the SSRS database.